# ASP.NET and Unity

Tags: asp.net-2.0, unity-container

First of all, is there a complete reference on Microsoft Unity?

I noticed today that, when I call "Configure" on the "UnityConfigurationSection" it configures and prepares all configuration mappings.

What if a class has a dependency on an object registered inside Unity. Does this class itself needs to be registered by Unity so that, Unity injects its dependency?

I am afraid that Unity would not inject a dependency on an Object, if that object is not registered into Unity. This is the case with "Page" class in ASP.NET.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unity has some well defined default behavior when working on classes that aren't registered ahead of time.

In the absence of registration, the container will look for the longest constructor, and it'll also look for attributes on the type ([Dependency] being the main one) to figure out what properties to inject.

If you don't want to use the attributes or the defaults don't match what you want, you'll need to configure the container to do the what you want.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your reply. I noticed that, even if a class is not registered with Unity, however it has dependencies, resolving the class with Unity works fine. As for ASP.NET Web Forms, since the Page class was created by ASP.NET runtime and not unity, that's why dependencies inside Web page cannot be resolved on their own. The trick is to call "BuildUp" method. This method is used to all Unity inject dependencies after the class has been created (and not created by Unity). Regards

Comment: @bhaidar, as an alternative of the call of BuildUp in the Page class, you can consider to implement and register you own httpmodule. For details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664534(PandP.50).aspx

Comment: Thanks Onof, I checked that website before and it makes sense to me now.